# Capturar ultimo registro de tabla

Tags: c#, sql-server

Tengo un dataGrid a este dataGrid le estoy sacando el ultimo registro de la tabla estos datos los capturo y los pongo en un XML

```
 private  async void metroTile1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (cmbSocioNegocio.Checked)
            {
                try
                {
                    ObtenerDatosNomina obtenerDatosNomina = new ObtenerDatosNomina();

                    DataGridViewCell dato = metroGrid1.Rows[0].Cells[0];

                    dato = metroGrid1.Rows[metroGrid1.Rows.Count - 1].Cells[2];
                    obtenerDatosNomina.cod_empl = dato.Value.ToString();

                    dato = metroGrid1.Rows[metroGrid1.Rows.Count - 1].Cells[8];
                    obtenerDatosNomina.nom_empl = dato.Value.ToString();

                    dato = metroGrid1.Rows[metroGrid1.Rows.Count - 1].Cells[7];
                    obtenerDatosNomina.ape_empl = dato.Value.ToString();

                    dato = metroGrid1.Rows[metroGrid1.Rows.Count - 1].Cells[22];
                    obtenerDatosNomina.dir_resi = dato.Value.ToString();

                    dato = metroGrid1.Rows[metroGrid1.Rows.Count - 1].Cells[25];
                    obtenerDatosNomina.tel_resi = dato.Value.ToString();

                    dato = metroGrid1.Rows[metroGrid1.Rows.Count - 1].Cells[53];
                    obtenerDatosNomina.eee_mail = dato.Value.ToString();

                    dato = metroGrid1.Rows[metroGrid1.Rows.Count - 1].Cells[55];
                    obtenerDatosNomina.tel_movi = dato.Value.ToString();

                    ProxyBL proxy = new ProxyBL();
                    var envioDatos = await proxy.EnviarPedidoL(obtenerDatosNomina);
                    Invoke((MethodInvoker)ListarLog);


                    //Indicas las opciones del servidor smtp mediante el que enviarás el correo (smtp + puerto)
                    SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587);

                    MailMessage message = new MailMessage("", "", "Socio  De  Negocios Creado en SAP BUSINESS ONE", "Se creo correctamente  el socio de negocios  "+ "Cc -> "+obtenerDatosNomina.cod_empl + " Nombre de SN -> " +obtenerDatosNomina.nom_empl);

                    //De forma alternativa, y por si quieres enviar html, puedes especificar el mensaje asi
                    //message.Body = "Se creo correctamente  el socio de negocios "+ obtenerDatosNomina.cod_empl + obtenerDatosNomina.nom_empl;

                    //Si tu servidor smtp necesita credenciales , las pones asi
                    client.EnableSsl = true;
                    client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("", "");

                    //Finalmente envias el mensaje
                    client.Send(message);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error al enviar ", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                }
            }
            else
                MessageBox.Show("Debes escoger un tipo de integracion");
            }
```

Lo que quiero es no hacerlo con Rows.Count si  no con una consulta de SQL server 
ya tengo la consulta que es un procedimiento almacenado

```
  public DataTable UltimoRegistro()
        {
            DataTable Tabla = new DataTable();
            Comando.Connection = Conexionsql.AbrirConexion();
            Comando.CommandText = "SP_Ultimo_Registro";
            Comando.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            LeerFilas = Comando.ExecuteReader();
            Tabla.Load(LeerFilas);
            LeerFilas.Close();
            Conexionsql.CerrarConexion();
            return Tabla;
        }
```

Como cambiar EL Rows.Count por el procedimiento para estar mas seguro que siempre va coger el ultimo

acá instancia el procedimiento

```
 Consultas consultas = new Consultas();
 metroGrid1.DataSource = consultas.UltimoRegistro();
```

Procedimiento sql server

```
CREATE PROC SP_Ultimo_Registro
AS
Select   max(act_hora)  from bi_emple
GO
```

Comment: A que llamas el ultimo registro? porque no hay "tecnicamente" un ultimo registro de una tabla, a menos que apliques una clausula order by a tu sql

Comment: Que te devuelve el metodo ultimo registro, podrias mostrar lo que hace el sp

Comment: Ya puse el procedimiento en la pregunta el coge el ultimo registro por la fecha por que la tabla no tiene mas campos para saber cual fue el ultimo, solo con fecha puede ver cual fue

Comment: @gbianchi coge el ultimo registro ingresado a la tabla con un order by si, pero la tabla no tiene ningún campo auto increment me toco mirar el ultimo por la fecha

Comment: Pero entonces no entiendo tu pregunta. Cual es el problema de agarrar el registro por la fecha?

Comment: No se como quitar el Rows.Count  y en vez de coger el ultimo registro así, poner el procedimiento

Comment: @gbianchi Me ayudas ¿?

Comment: No entiendo a que. Tu SP solo devuelve un dato (o no estas mostrando tu SP real). Con ese dato, no se que queres hacer. O con ese dato, queres ir devuelta a la base de datos y traer el registro relacionado a ese dato? O sea, quitar el row.count no es una pregunta en si. Es hagan algo por mi. La pregunta seria, tengo este SP que me devuelve un valor, y ahora necesito obtener el registro que cumple con ese valor. Probe esto (que probaste?) y no funciono.. que puedo estar haciendo mal? si no, parece que necesitaras que lo escribieramos por vos ;)

Comment: Lo que quiero es no contar la fila con el Rows.Count en vez de contarlo así, quiero llamar el procedimiento almacenado que trae el ultimo registro es lo mismo solo que lo va traer es el procedimiento

Answer (score 0):

Creo que lo que necesitas es cambiar el procedimiento almacenado. Una forma (entre otras) de obtener la última fila insertada sería está:

```
select top 1 * from bi_emple order by act_hora desc
```

Aunque si el campo act_hora tiene fecha y hora de actualización (no de creación) lo que recuperará será la última fila actualizada, que puede coincidir o no con la última insertada.

Answer (score -1):

La consulta sql solo arroja un valor: max(act_hora) el cual va a quedar guardado en el DataTable de la funcion UltimoRegistro().

Por tanto la tabla solo va a tener una vila y una columna

Para llamar ese valor lo unico que hay que hacer es mirar el valor de Tabla.Rows[0][0], aqui puedes convertirlo con ToString() a texto o utilizar alguna funcion de conversion dependidendo del tipo de dato que se arroja en el procedimiento almacenado de SQL